# In consumer theory, shouldn't necessity good and neutral good be different ? What will be the IC and utility function for both?

Tags: microeconomics, utility, consumer-theory, choice-theory

Necessity good for example salt, which regardless of income has to be consumed at certain quantity.

But neutral good for example is Suppliments for a healthy person which regardless of income he/she does not consume and doesn't care about.

Comment: Is there a source that tells you necessity goods and neutral goods are the same? Please quote it/and or link to it.

Comment: What do exactly do you mean by "*What will be the IC and utility function for both*"?